# Problems decompressing a gzip archive in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzip

I grabbed the following code somewhere off the Internet, and I am using it to decompress gzip files, such as http://wwwmaster.postgresql.org/download/mirrors-ftp/pgadmin3/release/v1.8.4/src/pgadmin3-1.8.4.tar.gz, but when I run It, I get an exception, stating that the magic number doesn't match.

```
public byte[] Download(string pUrl) {
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(pUrl);
    return UnGzip(bytes, 0);
}

private static byte[] UnGzip(byte[] data, int start) {
    int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, data.Length - 4);
    byte[] uncompressedData = new byte[size];
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(data, start, (data.Length - start));
    memStream.Position = 0;
    GZipStream gzStream = new GZipStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

    try {
        gzStream.Read(uncompressedData, 0, size);
    } catch (Exception gzError) {
        throw;
    }

    gzStream.Close();
    return uncompressedData;
}
```

What's wrong with the code that would cause this problem?

Comment: Can you show the code that gets the byte[] data array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the URL you specified in your question doesn't actually give a gzip file. It takes the browser to a page where you select a mirror.

If you temporarily change your `Download` method to use:

```
string text = wc.DownloadString(pUrl);
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

you'll see all the HTML for mirror selection.

If you use a URL which is the *actual* gz file, e.g. http://wwwmaster.postgresql.org/redir/170/h/pgadmin3/release/v1.8.4/src/pgadmin3-1.8.4.tar.gz then it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the GZipStream to read the file you linked, but it seems to decompress other GZip files just fine.  For example:

ftp://gnu.mirror.iweb.com/gnu/bash/bash-1.14.0-1.14.1.diff.gz

ftp://gnu.mirror.iweb.com/gnu/emacs/elisp-manual-21-2.8.tar.gz

Perhaps the file you linked is corrupt?  Or maybe it uses a non-standard or new GZip format.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) with some success with .zip files. According to the docs it also works with GZip. You might give this guy's library a try.

Comment: DotNetZip does GZIP, just the same way that the built-in GZipStream class does.  Using DotNetZip wouldn't actually change the code offered by the OP, except for the namespaces. The main benefit to using DotNetZip is that it is more effective in compression. No advantage in decompression.

Answer (score -1):

.NET does not support the [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29) format. `gzip` is simply a byte compressor. Tar is the container format.

Formats like [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) and [RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR), combines both these steps for you, but they are not good for streaming compression.

If I remember correctly, [SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpziplib.com/) has support for tar.